Extract substrings from dataframe column, insert into new column as integers
I have a dataframe, 'sp', with a column, 'RouteIdentifier', which contains a state route and additional noise. I want to get the numerical substring from each row, preferably without leading 0s, and place it as an int into a new column.
What I've succeeded in doing is extracting the numbers, but they are inserted into the new column as list objects (e.g. '012d' -> [012]).
sp.insert(1, 'StateRoute', [re.findall(r'\d+', x) for x in sp['RouteIdentifier']])


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

IIUC, you want to extract one numerical substring per row, and store them as integer.
Data sample
import pandas as pd

data = {'RouteIdentifier': ['route 012d', 'route 010noise'],
        'Col': ['hello', 'world']}

sp = pd.DataFrame(data)

sp

  RouteIdentifier    Col
0      route 012d  hello
1  route 010noise  world

Code
sp.insert(1, 'StateRoute', 
          sp['RouteIdentifier'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0].astype(int))

sp

  RouteIdentifier  StateRoute    Col
0      route 012d          12  hello
1  route 010noise          10  world

Explanation

Use Series.str.extract with a capturing group: r'(\d+)' instead of r'\d+'.
Select the column from the resulting df (default 0), and cast to int with Series.astype.
df.insert adds the series at a specific location. If you just want to add it at the end, simply assign sp['StateRoute'] = ....

Intermediate
sp['RouteIdentifier'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')

     0
0  012 # < `astype(int)` will remove leading zeros
1  010


If you're happy with your current approach, just modify the regex to avoid leading zeros and convert the strings to integers:
sp.insert(1, 'StateRoute',
          [list(map(int, re.findall(r'[1-9]\d*', x)))
           for x in sp['RouteIdentifier']])

Regex demo
